# Rearrange a number to get the largest number - JAVA

Tags: java, random, integer, int

I have generated a random 4 digit number, I now need to take the number and re-arrange it to create the largest possible - for example if i generated 3982 I then want to rearrange it to create 9832 (in a new variable) I also need to rearrange it to become the smallest (2389) in another new variable.. how do i do this?

So far I have...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInteger = randomGenerator.nextInt(9999);
    System.out.println(String.format("%04d", randomInteger));
```

Comment: Great start. Have you encountered any issue?

Comment: Have you considered sorting the digits?

Comment: I'm new to java and have nooooo idea how to ... I'm new to programming in general

Comment: Then follow a tutorial. This is not what this site is for.

Comment: Break this problem down. First you need to split the string into characters right? then convert these to digits so you can compare them and sort them. Do a bit of research, there are a lot of Java examples on the web. Try to solve this bit by bit.

Comment: And it's important that *you* solve it. That's what the homework is for. We can give you hints. But solving it for you would be harmful

Answer (score 5):

I think your teacher wants to test you three things:

**1)** How to generate a random 4 digit integer.

**2)** How to break down the integer into 4 digits

**3)** How to sort the 4 digits

Each of the three things should have been taught in introductory java course. So visit your notes.

Answer (score 3):

You could start by thinking about how you could extract the digits mathematically. Try it on paper - no java required. Then you can have a stab at doing the java. If you're still stuck then you can elaborate the question for more help.